# install spree with rails 4.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree

I was trying to install spree as an e-commerce solution with rails 4.1.0.
I followed the guide from https://github.com/spree/spree and installed the spree gem by adding "gem 'spree' " to my Gemfile.
'Bundle install' just worked fine but I found this in my console:

...
Using spree_api 0.30.1
Using spree_auth 0.30.1
Using spree_dash 0.30.1
Using spree_promo 0.30.1
Using spree_sample 0.30.1
Using spree 0.30.1
...

Spree 0.30.1 did not work well with my project and caused lots of bugs.
When I changed my rails version to 4.2.5 everything was ok.
The question is why spree chooses to use 0.30.1 and is there anyone has met this problem?
Many thanks to anyone who replies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure, do you know Solidus? Solidus is a Spree's fork pretty active.
https://solidus.io/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will suggest you to change your version. Spree current version is now 3.0.0. As you mentioned you using spree 0.30.0 which is very old version. Please upgrade to spree 3.0.0 which is the latest lot of features are new and fewer bugs in the new version. [spree_3.0.0](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/release_notes/spree_3_0_0.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must have followed the instructions at master branch, so you installed the 3.1.beta version.

Try installing the spree using the 3.0.7 version by  replacing the

> spree install

statement with

> spree install my_store --branch "3-0-stable"

This should work. If you want older versions like 2.4 stable follow the instructions from different branch.

If you want to  use the older versions like 3.0.3 you will have to change the hash of spree in Gemfile  to d1a2d1b2aa4e23a40517b6905b972b4319d332d0, or even better fork spree and reset to desired hash like for example d1a2d1b2aa4e23a40517b6905b972b4319d332d0 and change path in gemfile